# How to keep text format from a getElementById in javascript?

Tags: javascript, mysql, line-breaks, text-formatting

I store a text in a mysql database, and then I call it back and show it in a div with the following:

```
document.getElementById("mensaje").innerHTML = html;
```

But when it displays the text it doesn't keep the brake lines.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Hows does your code look like ? Make sure it is executable...

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode and encode:

With JavaScript:

**Option1:**

```
encodeURI('string to database');
decodeURI('string from database');
```

**Option2:**

```
encodeURIComponent('string to database');
decodeURIComponent('string from database');
```

With PHP:

**Option3:**

```
<?php
htmlentities($strToDB);
echo html_entity_decode($strFromDB);
?>
```

Comment: I guess it should encode and decode not encode and encode

Comment: I tried and it didnt work, I think javascript getElementById just display what is written in the sql field raw, not like in php that if you use echo it pass it like html line.

I don't know how to pass it in html and not displaying it in the screen raw

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing data from textarea then before storing data in database you can do

```
<?php
message = nl2br(message);
?>
```

It'll add HTML line breaks where it detects any line break.

Comment: I tried but shows me the <br/>... I think javascript getElementById just display what is written in the sql field raw, not like in php that if you use echo it pass it like html line.